# Java TESSERACT create byte[] instead of pdf file - tessInstance.createDocuments()

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

Is it possible to generate with Tess4j the byte[] of a PDF with OCR instead of a physical file?

I need to make PDF files searchable via OCR, it works but I would like to avoid this step.

```
Tesseract tessInst = new Tesseract();
tessInst.setDatapath("C:\\Tess4J");
List<RenderedFormat> list = new ArrayList<RenderedFormat>();
list.add(RenderedFormat.PDF);
tessInst.createDocuments(inputFile.getPath(), "C:\\a\\b\\b\\Tess4J\\filename", list); // i dont want to create this, i just need a byte[]!
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Tesseract does not support it. `TessPDFRendererCreate` expects a string for file path as input.

https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessapi/5.x/a00008.html